# Error during building setup script in Python

Tags: python, pyqt, setuptools, pyinstaller, cpython

I have next case:

1. Desktop application with Python + PySide
2. Want to use PYD-file (mycore.pyd) in my application
3. There is one dependency in mycore.pyx file to Padding module

   - this Padding module already installed to the system
4. I build Setup.py and get converted PYX-file to PYD-file, that I use in application

What I got:

- Once I run my application under PyCharm => everything is OK
- when I build application with PyInstaller approach and run the application from cmd => I catch an error "No named module Padding (requests etc)"

Example of setup.py file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize


extensions = ["mycore.pyx"]

setup(
    name='mycore',
    version='1.0',
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions),
    #packages=['Padding'], - once tried => "error: package directory 'Padding' does not exist"
)
```

Any ideas or advises would be great!

**UPDATE**

Also tried variant with `setup_tools`, also without success:

```
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from setuptools import setup, find_packages, Extension, Command


setup(name='mycore',
      packages = find_packages(),
      version=1.0,
      include_package_data=True,
      platforms=['all'],
      ext_modules=[Extension("mycore", ['mycore.c'])],
      #extra_require = {"Padding"} - also nothing
      )
```

Comment: Did you try using 'setuptools.find_packages()           'https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#using-find-packages

Comment: I tried to use the `setup_tools`, but still have the same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask *PyInstaller* to include the required module during the build process. It seems that the easiest way to do so is with the [`--hidden-import`](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#options-for-finding-imported-modules-and-libraries) argument:

> `--hidden-import=modulename`
>   Name an imported *Python* module that is not visible in your code. The module will be included as if it was named in an `import` statement. This option can be given more than once.

Thus, please add the following argument when building the application:

`--hidden-import=Padding`

---

**EDIT:**

Try importing all required modules (that trigger an error) in a separate `*.py` file, rather than in a `*.pyx` \ `*.pyd` file. It's an ugly workaround but might solve the issue nonetheless.

Consider using an `__init__.py` file for this scenario.

Comment: Still having the same issue:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "./build/win64\app\out00-PYZ.pyz\src.config", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 409, in load_module
    module = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, filename, self._c_ext_tuple)
  File "ovocore.pyx", line 4, in init src.ovocore (ovocore.c:11304)
ImportError: No module named Padding`

Comment: Does this occur during the build process or when executing the program?

Comment: After executing, compiling is OK

Comment: Can you join me in [this chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85227/pyinstaller)?

Comment: No need to use `--hidden-import=Padding` only need to move py-files in `__init__.py` (as example). Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a setup.py (https://github.com/robintiwari/django-me/blob/master/setup.py) file that i recently created that works and was having similar issue and I would agree with @Sanju to use setuptools.find_packages(). It fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the problem is that PyInstaller doesn't see packages imported by cython code, so it doesn't include it with the bundles applications.

There must be a way to tell PyInstaller to include the Padding package.

I can't tell you how -- never used it, but this is how you deal with it with py2exe and py2app.